# Console app with Ruby

Tags: ruby, console, command-line-interface

I wrote a ruby script to connect me into IRC servers, but I ran into a problem: while my code does wait for user input, the activity received breaks the text apart. Clarifying: let's say you want to write "the quick brown fox died", but by the time you typed "the quic", someone left the #ruby channel. Then you kept typing, and some other event happened. Then, my screen looks like this:

```
the quic
#> u17r4h4x0r left #ruby: "f u n00bs"
k brow
#> u17r4h4x0r joined #ruby
n fox died
```

And when I hit ENTER, then I send "the quick brown fox died".

Is there any way to make incoming events avoid this first line, leaving it only for user inputs?

Thanks =]

**UPDATE**

Code: https://github.com/thyagobr/mesmer/blob/master/client.rb#L36

Line 36 is where I'm receiving input.

Comment: You need to provide code related to this issue for anyone to be able to help you on this.

Comment: I suggest using a library like ncurses or termbox